# Laravel Artisan Command show verbose error messages

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

Typically I run a laravel artisan command like

```
php artisan Command -v
```

and if there is an error I can find the file/line#, using the -v flag.

For some reason the -v is not working on one of my commands. I am therefore receiving a pretty limited error message:

`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to a member function getArgument() on null`

This command happens to be calling some code that is extending someone else's code.

Any ideas how to get the file/line output in the error message?

Comment: Is it not in your log file ( `storage/logs/laravel.log` )?

Comment: My experience with the log file is that it logs what the console states, which is the case here. Additionally, I guess I want the error immediately rather than going on a log file hunt.

Comment: Interesting that its not more verbose in the log file is this a public library or private one? Just wondering if you can work out if they are catching the exception in a particular way that is suppressing the full error.

Comment: Actually I do have some line numbers on some errors, still can't get the verbose error on the console

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Old, but relates to a questions / answer I had...

***...verbosity levels...***

```
// -v|vv|vvv Increase the verbosity of messages: 
//    1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
php artisan --verbose
```

Good reference here...
https://github.com/JesseObrien/laravel-cheatsheet (moved to github)

Comment: I can't even remember this error... obviously I carried on but hopefully it helps

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Link is broken, please fix

Answer (score 0):

It's been caught by `laravel`
You can dump the detail in the "handle" function in this file

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php
```